# Random NullPointerExceptions in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, nullpointerexception

My first question on SO.

So I am just starting to learn JavaFX, and I already have taken a year of normal Java coding at school, so I was a bit perplexed when I came across this problem:

I started creating a basic GUI in JavaFX Scene Builder which has a few buttons, a textField, and a statusIndicator, and when I click `buttonListen` I want `buttonToggle` to disappear and have the status indicator (`spinWheel`) appear. Here is the code for handling that:

```
@FXML
private TextField fieldDisplay;
private Button buttonToggle;
private Button buttonListen;
private ProgressIndicator spinWheel;

@FXML
private void ButtonListenListener(ActionEvent event){
    if(buttonToggle.isVisible()){
        buttonToggle.setVisible(false);
        spinWheel.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

All of that is contained within an FXMLDocumentController.java class for those familiar with JavaFX. However, when I run the program, there is a big long error stack, but it boils down to this statement saying that there is a nullPointer on one of my Buttons:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at javafxfirstproj.FXMLDocumentController.ButtonListenListener(FXMLDocumentController.java:45)
```

I've heard that JavaFX is riddled with bugs, so I'm wondering if this is a logic error in my code or if I've just run into one of the (supposedly) many bugs. Any and all help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd need to see more of your code (specifically, the FXML and the code that loads it) to be sure, but I'm guessing the problem is here:

```
@FXML
private TextField fieldDisplay;
private Button buttonToggle;
private Button buttonListen;
private ProgressIndicator spinWheel;
```

That `@FXML` notation only applies to the declaration *immediately* following it (the declaration of `fieldDisplay`). If `buttonToggle`, `buttonListen`, and `spinWheel` are also linked to FXML, you need to annotate each of them as well:

```
@FXML
private TextField fieldDisplay;
@FXML
private Button buttonToggle;
@FXML
private Button buttonListen;
@FXML
private ProgressIndicator spinWheel;
```

Comment: @user5047031 No problem! I actually taught a class that included JavaFX as one of the subjects, and this was a common problem students faced. It was interesting seeing it come up again. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating/declaring of Javafx components/nodes/control in FXML and you want to use it in the Java controller class then with each and every component that you want to use should have @FXML annotation with them. So in you code add FXML annotations

```
@FXML
private TextField fieldDisplay;
@FXML
private Button buttonToggle;
@FXML
private Button buttonListen;
@FXML
private ProgressIndicator spinWheel;
```

If you don't then these components are not assigned any objects thus when you use it like this

> if(buttonToggle.isVisible())

it will give you **NullPointerException**

Checkout [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/connecting_scenebuilder_edited_fxml_to) blog's **Connection to code** section